# Photoshop and file permissions after April 2018 Update

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, file-permissions, dropbox, windows-10-v1803

I have two Administrator user accounts on my computer, A and B. There's a common folder in A's Dropbox that I use for storing images, and that folder has full access permissions for both user A and B. Before the April 2018 update I could happily save any file I wanted to from User A to that folder, and open them with User B.

After installing the update, when I save images from Photoshop they only have permissions for A, and B has none. I've tried saving them multiple ways, and still only A has access. I can open the folder with A, make a copy of the file in the same folder and B has permissions for the copy. I can also save files from Notepad and other programs in that folder, and B will have access.

I have a feeling this isn't really specific to Photoshop, but I can't replicate the problem with another program. Obviously I can add permissions to each file individually, but that means I have to remember to do so which is not ideal.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is the path to the Dropbox folder?  I promise I have a reason for asking this question.

Comment: @Ramhound The path is `/Users/A/Dropbox/images/`.

Comment: You are going to battle this permission problem, every single time you install a feature update since the directory is within a user's directory.  You are going to have to repeat the same steps you did before to get it to work.  I suggest moving the folder to a more neutral location.

Comment: I had issues with this maybe 2 years ago, but all I remember doing was adding A and B with full permissions to `/Users/*` and `/Program Files/*`. Both accounts still have full permissions on the top level folders and child items (except the ones that Photoshop creates for some reason), what other steps are there?

Comment: I am suggesting you add and remove the user and reapply the permissions

Comment: That fixed it. I reapplied the permissions at the User directory level and had it set them to all child items. Now everything works. Oddly, before I did that I realized that the only issue I had was when I had Photoshop export a file to the directory (my standard workflow). If I saved the PSD or even the PNG directly to the images directory it had the correct permissions applied.